ios swiftui webview Print is not triggerring
i have an ios app built using swiftui that dipslays webview
the web app contains print function, it triggers correctly from web browser but its not triggering from the ios app
the print uses this library to print:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-to-print 
when we press on the print button we get this response on log:
0x10880a418 - [pageProxyID=7, webPageID=8, PID=69383] WebPageProxy::didFailLoadForFrame: frameID=642, isMainFrame=0, domain=NSURLErrorDomain, code=-999
the webview function inside the app:

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    var url:String
    enum WorkState: String {
           case initial
           case done
           case working
           case errorOccurred
       }
    let webView: WKWebView
    @State var workState: WorkState=WebView.WorkState.initial
    @Binding var showLoading : Bool
     
    init(url:String,showLoading:Binding<Bool>,mWorkState:WorkState) {
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero)
        self.url = url
        self._showLoading = showLoading
        self.workState = mWorkState
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        webView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator
        webView.allowsLinkPreview=true
        return webView
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
           switch self.workState {
           case .initial:
               //showLoading = true
               webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!))
           case .done:
               print("done")
              // showLoading = false
               break
           default:
               break
           }
       }

any help with this will be appreciated

Hi @dev mobile, please share your Coordinator class to reproduce the issue and what is not printing?
